# why is the histogram of Cr and Cb slightly changing when I am performing histogram matching in Y alone?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram, scikit-image

The code I used to match the histograms along with all the import statements:

```
import skimage.viewer
from skimage import data,io,color
from skimage import exposure
from skimage.exposure import match_histograms

ref1 = io.imread("drive/My Drive/Images_for_Adarsh/DSC_6139.JPG")
orig1 = io.imread("drive/My Drive/Images_for_Adarsh/DSC_6138.JPG")
ref = color.rgb2ycbcr(ref1)
orig = color.rgb2ycbcr(orig1)
f1 = match_histograms(orig, ref, multichannel=True)
f1[:,:,1] = orig[:,:,1]
f1[:,:,2] = orig[:,:,2]
f2 = color.ycbcr2rgb(f1)
```

The code I used to plot the histograms:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure

img1 = cv2.imread("drive/My Drive/Images_for_Adarsh/DSC_6176.JPG")
img2 = cv2.imread("drive/My Drive/Y Histogram_Match RESULTS/Y6176.JPG")
img1f = cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
img2f = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)
histr1 = cv2.calcHist([img1f],[0],mask,[256],[0,255])
histr2 = cv2.calcHist([img2f],[0],mask,[256],[0,255])
f = figure(num=None, figsize=(9, 5), dpi=400, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
plt.subplot(1 ,2 , 1)
plt.plot(histr1,color = 'pink')
plt.xlim([0,275])
plt.xlabel("Luminance")
plt.ylabel("No. of Pixels")

plt.subplot(1 ,2 , 2)
plt.plot(histr2,color = 'pink')
plt.xlim([0,275])
plt.xlabel("Luminance")
plt.ylabel("No. of Pixels")

a1 = f.add_subplot(121)
a2 = f.add_subplot(122)
f.suptitle("DSC_6176 -- LUMINANCE HISTOGRAM", fontsize=16)
a1.title.set_text('ORIGINAL')
a2.title.set_text('RESULT(after Y value Histogram Matching)')


plt.subplots_adjust(left=None, bottom=None, right=None, top=None, wspace=0.45, hspace=None)
plt.savefig("drive/My Drive/histograms Y Matching/Luminance6176.JPG",dpi = 400)
```

[This is the Luminance histogram for the original image on the left and that of final result on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYxlR.jpg)

[This is the Cb histogram for the original image on the left and that of final result on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pofSn.jpg)

[This is the Cr histogram for the original image on the left and that of final result on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEEWj.jpg)

[This is the input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFG4A.jpg)

[This is the reference image(I want the luminance histogram of the input image to this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuT6W.jpg)

Here, I am performing histogram matching on the luminance('Y' value in YCRCB). For this, I am performing histogram matching on all 3 channels, Y, Cr, and Cb, and then copying Cr and Cb from the original image and putting it in my final image. Hence, in effect, my code only modifies the luminance while Cr and Cb are unchanged. However, when I am plotting the histograms for my 3 channels, there is slight variation Cr and Cb channels. I am not able to understand this. Why is this happening? Please help! Thanks in advance!
I have added the Luminance(Y), Cb, and Cr histograms of the original image and result for your reference.

Comment: Please add the information necessary to make a *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"*, namely your input images, all the `import` and other statements you have removed and the code that creates the 2 histograms you show. Thank you.

Comment: Post your full code showing your imports. Some tools use images as RGB and OpenCV uses BGR.

Comment: I have added the full code, input image, and histograms of luminance, Cr and Cb as per what you had asked.

Comment: Mmmm... firstly, the two images you used for histogram matching are not the same two images you used for plotting. Secondly, you used the **skimage** routines to open the JPEGs the first time and the **OpenCV** routines to open the JPEGs for plotting - they will not necessarily give the same pixel values. Thirdly, you used the **skimage** conversion from RGB to YCbCr initially then for plotting you used the **OpenCV** routine.

Comment: Besides what Mark said, if you take YCbCr values, convert to RGB, round, then convert back to YCbCr, you’ll end up with slightly different values, and potentially very different values if Y is very large or very small.

Comment: Yes Mark, even I was sceptical about using skimage in the first routine and OpenCV in the second. However, I was not able to find a library function in OpenCV, to perform histogram matching. Is there one? If not, what are the other alternatives I can use so that I avoid using skimage (because everywhere else, I am using OpenCV).

Comment: Hey Cris, thanks for that information. I did not know that reading the image using OpenCV and skimage would yield slightly different pixel values. I want to perform histogram matching but unfortunately, I was not able to a function in OpenCV which is why I had to use skimage for that purpose. Which other option is available that would yield better results?